# How to use OneHotEncoder encoding over multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a DataFrame of shape (85,78) each row correspondin to a particular area and with values as different restaurant categories like 'Bakery','Cafe','BBQ Joint'etc.Total unique categories = 175.

I need to calculate top categories per each area and to do this i want to encode the data set.
But OneHotEncoding gives me a total of 949 rows instead of 175 unique rows.It seems like it is doing fit_transform for each column.

pd.get_dummies is doing the same by adding suffix (0,1,2..etc) to each category if repeated along other columns.

I want the data frame to have just 175 columns so that I can calculate their sum according to each area.

[image: DataFrame]

Comment: yes, that is not an error, one-hot encoding converts each unique field into it own column

Comment: replace the `0`s with NaN, then `stack`. call `pd.get_dummies` on that longer Series and now you can `groupby(level=0).max()` to get the dummies for each original row in your DataFrame.

Comment: dude can i say you are genius.Thank you.It works.

Comment: @Allaye does it track if a unique value in 2nd column has been already considered as unique in the 1st column.I guess it does'nt right?.Then how does one do OneHotEncoding over entire dataframe.